# If I grill a bacon-wrapped chicken skewer, does a significant amount of bacon fat seeps into the poultry?

Tags: chicken, bacon, skewers, grilled

I have cubes of chicken breast wrapped in bacon in a footlong bamboo skewer grilled in an electrical barbecue grill.

One of my guests said that if you remove the bacon and eat only the chicken, you get the flavor but not the fat. I was skeptical.

Does the fat content of the chicken meat increase significantly?

Comment: Making your own bacon has the side effect of greatly reducing the fat lost in the cooking process.

Answer (score 4):

Your cooking method will clearly increase the fat content of the dish.  If the bacon is removed after cooking, I don't think it is possible to say how much bacon fat remains.  There are probably multiple variables.  Even with some fat remaining on the surface, or possibly getting past the surface, removing the bacon itself would eliminate a significant amount of fat.  Simply because most of that fat resides in the bacon (though a bunch dripped off during cooking, and some stayed on the chicken), so the now bacon-less chicken would have more fat.  Whether or not that is significant, I don't think we can say, but I would assume that is what your guest meant...not that all traces of fat would be gone.

Comment: You could burn a blot of paper towel used on two pieces of chicken that had and didn't have bacon wrapped on it and measure the temp + duration to see if they vary "significantly". I once accidently lit the paper towel used to pat bacon on fire and it was _very_ obviously burning _much_ more intense than a plain paper towel burns...

Answer (score 0):

It won't "seep" in significantly at all, even if you left it for hours.   It'll coat the chicken though, and probably increase the fat content of the dish by a lot.